# Why am I getting this NameError? Am I not using this correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, nameerror

I'm not sure if i'm missing something or what, but this keeps giving me this error. I have read a few questions but they don't seem to be helping. I started learning python a few days ago, but what am I missing? I'm trying to except the error to try something else if an error occurs. I had this working on a different computer, but now it's not working for some reason? I'm using anaconda and jupyter.

```
import mechanize
from mechanize import ControlNotFoundError
import sys
from random import randint
import time
import csv

ipa=randint(1, 254)
ipb=randint(1, 254)

ip="131.156." + str(ipa) + "." + str(ipb)

ofile = "D:\\Downloads\\filename.csv"

url = "https://website.com"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots

names=[]
i=0
entries=80
with open(ofile) as csvDataFile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
for row in csvReader:
    names.append((row[0],row[1]))
csvDataFile.close()

for name,email in names:

ipa=randint(1, 254)
ipb=randint(1, 254)
ip="131.156." + str(ipa) + "." + str(ipb)    

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots
br.open(url) 

br.select_form(nr = 0)
while True:
    try:
        br.form.find_control( 'Entries[registration_ip]').readonly = False
        print ("Form found ")
        break
    except ControlNotFoundError:
        print ("ControlNotFoundError")
        br.open(url)
        br.select_form(nr = 0)
        br.form.find_control( 'Entries[registration_ip]').readonly = False
br.form.set_value(ip, 'Entries[registration_ip]')
br.form.set_value(name, 'Entries[full_name]') 
br.form.set_value(email, 'Entries[email]')

time.sleep(randint(1, 110))
time.sleep(random())

res = br.submit()
print (name + " " + email) 

content = res.read()
if (i > entries) : break
i+=1

time.sleep(randint(1, 200))
time.sleep(random())

with open("mechanize_results.html", "w") as f:
f.write(content)
```

Error:

```
ControlNotFoundError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e095be0c9792> in <module>()
 47             br.open(url)
 48             br.select_form(nr = 0)
---> 49             br.form.find_control( 
'Entries[registration_ip]').readonly = 
False
 50     br.form.set_value(ip, 'Entries[registration_ip]')
 51     br.form.set_value(name, 'Entries[full_name]')

C:\Users\Donald\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form_controls.pyc in 
find_control(self, name, type, kind, id, predicate, nr, label)
2329             raise ValueError(
2330                 "at least one argument must be supplied to specify 
control")
-> 2331         return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, 
predicate, nr)
2332 
2333 # ---------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\Donald\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form_controls.pyc in 
_find_control(self, name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
2422                                  description)
2423         elif not found:
-> 2424             raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching " + 
description)
2425         assert False
2426 
ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'Entries[registration_ip]'
```

Comment: please post your error code, the entire traceback

Comment: Added my traceback @0TTT0

Comment: Looks like you need to import that exception from where it was defined.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean @KlausD.

Comment: `ControlNotFoundError` is defined somewhere in mechanize, you have to import it from there.

Comment: Welp, now i'm afraid this has led me to a worse error @KlausD.

Comment: You fixed one error and got a few lines further in your code and got a new unrelated error. A new error means you should open a new question. Unluckily you have removed the original error message, which makes this question less useful for people having the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Until you post your detailed trace, here is what I noticed, and it is only at first glance.  You may be missing some indentations in your code.
- Your “with open(file)” has no activities associated with it.  Any functions calls and assignments that fall within the “with open” need to be indented under it.
- “for name,email in names” has the same problem
- “if (i > entries) : break” breaks out of a nonexistent loop.  I am guessing everything under “for name,email” should be indented as it belongs to it?

Looks like ControlNotFoundError is defined in mechanize
Reference it as “mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError”

Comment: I did post my full trace, didn't I? It's at the bottom of my code

Comment: If you are having side notes that will not answer the original question, please post them as comments not as an answer. Answers not related to the question might get down voted.

Comment: I edited my answer to actually include an "answer".  Please specify the reason for the down vote.